# Is antisymmetric the same as reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, equivalence-relations

Note: The following definitions from my book, Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications [7th ed, 598].

This is my book's definition for a reflexive relation
[image]

This is my book's definition for a anti symmetric relation
[image]

Is a reflexive relation just the same as a anti symmetric relation?  From what I've, the only way to meet that antisymmetric requirement is to have the same ordered pair, say an element a from Set A, (a,a). If you have anything other than the same ordered pair, (1,2) and (2,1), it will not meet the antisymmetric requirement. But the overall definition of reflexive relation is that it's the same ordered pair. Are they just two ways of saying the same thing? Is it possible to have one and not the other?

Comment: On $\{1,2\}$, the relation $\{(1,1)\}$ isn't reflexive, but it is symmetric. On the same set, $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$ is reflexive, but not symmetric.

Comment: @GitGud The question was about *anti*symmetric, not symmetric.  I'm preparing an answer now.

Comment: [Is there a relation that is irreflexive, anti-symmetric and not transitive?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704457/is-there-a-relation-that-is-irreflexive-anti-symmetric-and-not-transitive)

Comment: OK. My first example still works.

Comment: A nice, natural and somewhat commonly-encountered relation that is non-reflexive, and at the same time anti-symmetric in a non-vacuous way seems hard to come by.

Comment: @GitGud Would an empty relation be symmetric?

Comment: @committedandroider Yes, because $\forall x,y\left((x,y)\in \varnothing\implies (y,x)\in \varnothing\right)$ is a true statement.

Comment: @Arthur: A fairly natural example of a non-reflexive, anti-symmetric relation (on $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q,$ or $\mathbb R$) is $a \ge |b|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, antisymmetric is not the same as reflexive.

An example of a relation that is reflexive, but not antisymmetric is the relation
$$R={(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)}$$ on $$A={1,2}.$$  It is reflexive because for all elements of $A$ (which are $1$ and $2$), $(1,1)\in R$ and $(2,2)\in R$.  The relation is not anti-symmetric because $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are in $R$, but $1\not=2$.

An example of a relation that is not reflexive, but is antisymmetric is the empty relation $R=\emptyset$ on $A={1}$.  It doesn't have $(1,1)$ in it, but it is vacuously antisymmetric.

On a further note: reflexive is:
$$\forall a\in A, (a,a)\in R.$$

Anti-symmetric is 
$$\forall (a,b),(b,a)\in R, a=b.$$

Note that the statements have different hypotheses and conclusions (even though they look similar).

Comment: Would your second example be vacuously transitive as well?

Comment: @committedandroider The second example is transitive, but not vacuously transitive because $(1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are in $R$ and so is $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

No.

First, you can have a reflexive relation which is not antisymmetric. For example: an integer number $a$ is related to other integer $b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. This is not antysymmetric, because $2R4$ and $4R2$, but $2\neq 4$. But it is reflexive, since every integer has the same parity than itself.

Second, you can have an antysymmetric relation that it is not reflexive. The empty relation on a non empty set, for example: that is, a non empty set in which no element is related to any element (not even to itself).

Comment: What would be an example of a non empty set in which no element is related to any element?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same thing. For example, on $\mathbb R$ the strict inequality is anti-symmetric but not reflexive.... If you want one which is not vacuous, change it to be $\leq $ if at least one of the numbers is negative.

On $\mathbb Z$, if we define $(x,y) \in R$ if and only if $x-y$ is even, then this is reflexive but not santi-ymmetric.

Comment: $<_{\Bbb R }$ is a familiar example, but unfortunately the anti-symmetric property is vacuous.

Comment: @MJD doesn't it has to be vacuous in some sense? By this there must exists an $x$ such that it is vacuous at for all pairs including $x$...

Comment: @N.S. What does the $\sim$ mean? I found it on here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference but that doesn't explain what it means

Comment: @committedandroider I am used to write $a \sim b$ instead of $(a,b)$ for a relation... I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Reflexivity *requires* all elements to be both way related with themselves.  However, this does *not* prohibit non-equal elements from being both way related with each other.

That is:  $\qquad\forall a\in A: (a,a)\in R$ from which we can prove: $$\forall a\in A\;\forall b\in A:\Big(a=b \;\to\; (a,b)\in R \wedge (b,a)\in R\Big)$$

Antisymetricality *requires* any two elements which are both way related with each other to be equal.  Which means it *prohibits* non-equal elements from being both-way related to each other; however, this does *not* require all elements to be both way related with themselves.
$$\forall a\in A, \forall b\in A:\Big((a,b)\in R \wedge (b,a)\in R \;\to\; a=b\Big)$$
Or via contraposition: $\qquad\forall a\in A, \forall b\in A:\Big(a\neq b \;\to\; (a,b)\notin R \vee (b,a)\notin R\Big)$

Thus they are not the same thing.

---

Examples are easy to generate.  From the set $A=\{0, 1\}$ The following relations are:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
R & \text{Reflexive} & \text{Antisymmetric}
\\ \hline
\{(0,0), (1,1)\} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes}
\\
\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\} & \text{Yes} & \text{No}
\\
\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)\} & \text{No} & \text{No}
\\
\{(0,0), (0,1)\} & \text{No} & \text{Yes}
\end{array}$$